# Different radius to box-shadow and div

Tags: html, css

I want to apply different `border-radius` to box-shadow and div(on which box shadow is applied). Want to make something like this.
https://www.screencast.com/t/mEjBxMnbt

I make div and apply box-shadow and then apply `border-radius:1px 0 0 1px` to div which gives radius to `box shadow` which is fine but I want to give more border-radius to my div without changing my box-shadow radius.Can apply css only on div can't wrap it up or take parent container for it.

Please see link for more understanding.

Tried this is far

https://codepen.io/naveen_dharni/pen/Kqdyer

Comment: can you post working fiddle? What have you done so far ?

Comment: Post my work link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't your problem be solved with overlapping multiple shadows?

```css
body
{
  background-color:pink;
  padding-left:20px;
}
div
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:8px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 
      -27px -27px 0 -9px blue,
      -27px 27px 0 -9px blue,
      -9px -9px 0 9px blue,
       -9px 9px 0 9px blue,
       9px -9px 0 9px blue,
       9px 9px 0 9px blue;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
div:first-child {
  box-shadow:
      -9px -9px 0 9px blue,
       -9px 9px 0 9px blue,
       9px -9px 0 9px blue,
       9px 9px 0 9px blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div><!-- no space between inline-blocks to make gaps predictable
--><div></div><!--
--><div></div><!--
--><div></div>
```

Comment: Please explain this, i didn't understand as i have to use this in my server which has some compatibility issues so, i have to adjust it accordingly can't copy your full code.

Comment: @naveendharni, please check this animated example that shows how this shadow shape is created: https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/Moarwg. In my original example, all `div`s except the 1st one also have two more shadows that hide the "holes" between corners to make the "border" look solid and uniform, they are created similarly.

Answer (score 0):

hi border radius effects the box shadow of the div element ..
you could do something like this using the pseudo elements

html

```
<div></div>
```

css

```
div
{
  top:50px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 18px #DCD7E3;
  border-radius: 1px 0 0 1px;
  border-radius:500px;
  position: relative;
  margin:auto;
}

div::after
{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-50%;
  right:-50%;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  height:120%;
  width:120%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

Here is a link for reference [codepen link](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/dRYVQx?editors=1100)

Hope this works..